# Laravel paginate not working using with query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-pagination

I can view all my posts and include their respective owner and category in the query.

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::with('user', 'category')->get();
    return response()->json([
        'posts' => $posts, 
    ], 200);
}
```

**Note:** I used the with helper because thr front-end of the site is in vuejs.

Now I want to add pagination in my code but I get the following error:

```
"Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with does not exist."
```

This is what I tried:

```
$posts = Post::paginate(2)->with('user', 'category')->get();
```

How can I use the laravel pagination?

Comment: **->get();** when used you get all records in db wich is wrapped in **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection** instance. Can you show that code where do paginate?

Comment: @Davit I just updated my question

Comment: Try my answer. It will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For get the result you must be use `paginate, get, first` methods the end of the query

```
Post::with('user', 'category')->paginate(2);
```

Comment: Upvoted. So the get after the paginate does not work. Your answer is top

Comment: I don't understand my answer is not solve your problem??

Comment: Yes it did. Spot on. Upvoted and marked as favourite